# which is the equal syntax "Ext.BoxComponent" in Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, extjs, extjs4.1

I have to show a table in a widget based on the device(mobile, laptop, tablet) selected by user.

For Desktop/Laptop I am loading ExtJs libraries. I wrote following code which is working fine.

> var container = new Ext.BoxComponent({    id: "demoBox"  });

for mobile I load Jquery Mobile libraries. I am getting an error like

> Uncaught Reference Error: Ext is not defined

. could you tell me which is equal component for 'Box Component' in Jquery mobile.

Comment: ExtJS 4.1 doesn't have a BoxComponent. BoxComponent was last used in ExtJS 3.4 as per the docs. Please repair your tags.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery Mobile and ExtJS are not compatible in a way that you could copy over the code, optimize and be done with it. JQuery requires you to write HTML code, ExtJS doesn't. If you have a working ExtJS application, the best way to go mobile is ExtJS6-modern, previously called Sencha Touch.

The way you write JQuery Mobile means that you don't need a BoxComponent there. You would just write a bit of HTML/CSS - a DIV with a certain width and height - and be done with it.